# Postgres: Insert if not exists, otherwise return the row

Tags: sql, postgresql

In one SQL statement, I am trying to insert a row, and if that fails due to a constraint, then return the existing row.

I have:

```
INSERT INTO session (token, expiry) SELECT 'abcdefg', '2014-05-14 20:25:12.279667' WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM session where token= 'abcdefg');
```

The `token` column has a unique constraint. I've tried appending `RETURNING *` at the end, but that still does not return the existing row.

Why is this? I thought my last `SELECT` statement will be executed and returned. Any ideas?

Note: I cannot use a Postgres function or multiple SQL statements due to some complicated race condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WITH d(t, e) AS ( VALUES ('abcdefg', '2014-05-14 20:25:12.279667')),
  t AS (SELECT token FROM session, d WHERE token=t),
  i AS (INSERT INTO session (token, expiry) 
           SELECT t, e FROM d WHERE t NOT IN (SELECT token FROM t))
SELECT t,e FROM d WHERE t IN (SELECT token FROM t);
```

The query first makes a CTE (Common Table Expression) **d** with the data you want to insert

Then it makes a CTE **t** with the token in session that match the token in **d** (or empty if no match).

Then it uses CTE **i** to insert the row from **d** if it has no match in **t** into **session**.

And finally it returns the row from **d** if it did have a match in **t**.

BTW this also works with multiple rows.

Comment: What does CTE mean?

Comment: @SepSol Common Table Expression, I have added it in the answer also