# Postgres: insert and return ID or return id of exisitng row

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I need to tune this statement to return the id if row exists or insert row if not exists based on 2 parameters:

```
WITH d(t, e) AS ( VALUES (1, current_timestamp)),
  t AS (SELECT id FROM attendance, d WHERE start = e and user_id = t),
  i AS (INSERT INTO attendance (user_id, start) 
           SELECT t, e FROM d WHERE t NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t))
SELECT t,e FROM d WHERE t IN (SELECT id FROM t);
```

`1` and `current_timestamp` needs to be parametric. I will use this from nodejs. I have just used pgsql function because when I supplement timestamp like `'2016-08-18T14:51:42.333Z'` it is saying that I need to convert it.

Current state is that with `current_timestamp` function, it will insert the new row but not return it's id.

This is what I have constructed with help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573815/postgres-insert-if-not-exists-otherwise-return-the-row) thread.

Thanks for solutions.

Comment: Have you seen this? - [SELECT ⇒ INSERT](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/examples/select-insert.md). It has some bearing on your question, as far as [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) is concerned, plus some useful links at the end ;)

Comment: that is very handy! thanks vitaly-t!